# How to use Chef Opscode with AWS autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, autoscaling

I have been facing issues with integrating chef with AWS autoscale.

In most of my searches it tells about bootstrapping an instance and then using it's AMI to launch other instance in just the same way.

Basic issue is, Chef recognises each host with it's hostname, which in the above case is all going to be same. However, I was hoping for something like a Role which integrates in to AWS and does the thing better for me. Any help/Ideas will be appreciated. I just hope someone has done it already.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of options but the general flow looks like this:

1. Create an AMI with Chef pre-installed and with your org validator key and a `client.rb` with the server URL set. Packer is great for this. Technically optional, you could do this from the user-data script, but it saves a few seconds on each server launch.
2. Configure the `UserData` field on the ASG to be a script (or cloud-init config if you want to get fancy but we'll ignore that option for now) that launches `chef-client -r 'role[myrole]` where `myrole` is usually based on the type of ASG you are building. This will use the validator key to register with the Chef Server automatically and set the run list based on the command line you give. You can use similar arguments to set the environment or policy name if you are using those features.
3. Include the `chef-client` cookbook/recipe in that role to install Chef as a daemon on the machine and to remove the validator key.